# How to set indent spaces for round bracket?

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I want to modify the indent for function definition after clicking Return in the round bracket like the screenshot below. I want it to work in real-time rather than save and format mode. Is there a good idea about how to set up this function in the VSCODE?

I appreciate your help.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSd90.png)